# Custom items in custom recipes

Tags: parameters, minecraft, bukkit

So I'm making fundy's weird food thing as a plugin instead of a mod and I would need to make a custom recipe for the steakchop + cooked cod to make the steakcochop. But the steakchop is also a custom item, and I can't seem to do it by doing `(Class name).(Item)` like in this case `ItemManager.Steakchop`. It tells me that I need to use an ItemStack. Can someone tell me what I need to put into the `setIngredient` parameter if I want the 2nd parameter to be the Steakchop?

Here is what I tried...

 `fundy.setIngredient('S', ItemManager.SteakChop);`

Comment: Could you provide what you've tried so far as well as what Bukkit version you're using (e.g. 1.16)

Comment: I'm using 1.16.5 bukkit

Answer (score 0):

Although the method is deprecated, from 1.13 you can use [`RecipeChoice.ExactChoice`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/RecipeChoice.ExactChoice.html).

```java
ItemStack resultItem = /*your desired result custom stack*/
NamespacedKey key = new NamespacedKey(plugin, "myCustomResult");
ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(key, resultItem);
recipe.setIngredient(/*your shaped item key*/, new RecipeChoice.ExactChoice(/*your custom item stack*/));
recipe.shape(/*your shape*/);
Bukkit.addRecipe(recipe);
```

Because `ExactChoice` is deprecated, this will change or be removed in future versions so be aware of that.

Comment: The deprecated thing is returning null, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong or because I'm using 1.16.5 bukkit (and there is no way I'm going back to 1.13 bukkit man no)

Comment: I chose my wording of 'from 1.13' carefully so that the answer will still be valid in the future when this method inevitably changes. I asked what Bukkit version you are using already and made sure that it works on 1.16.5. I added the note about it being untested because I could not fully test it due to the question not having a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).